# Use some rows as columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I'm a newbie to stackoverflow and python, so please bear with me.

I have data in the following format:

| Date | Colour | Time | date_time | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/10/2021 | Blue | 09:30 | 31/10/2021 09:30 | 13 |
| 01/11/2021 | Blue | 09:40 | 01/11/2021 09:40 | 78 |
| 02/11/2021 | Red | 09:45 | 02/11/2021 09:45 | 69 |
| 09/11/2021 | Red | 09:55 | 09/11/2021 09:55 | 90 |
| 14/11/2021 | Red | 10:30 | 14/11/2021 10:30 | 24 |
| 16/11/2021 | Red | 10:40 | 16/11/2021 10:40 | 20 |
| 22/11/2021 | Green | 10:45 | 22/11/2021 10:45 | 61 |
| 23/11/2021 | Blue | 11:05 | 23/11/2021 11:05 | 62 |
| 26/11/2021 | Blue | 12:00 | 26/11/2021 12:00 | 80 |

Basically it represents daily values for the quantity of Blue items, quantity of Red items, quantity of Green items, etc.

I want to put this data in a format (output to a CSV file) that makes it easier to create a line graph. (E.g. with X as the Week Commencing date, Y as Quantity total for each colour for that week, and a line representing each color.)

So I'd want to format the data into a table like the below instead:

| Week commencing | Total blue | Total red | Total green |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | 32 | 42 | 213 |  |
| 2021-01-18 | 45 | 33 | 32 |  |
| 2021-01-25 | 24 | 67 | 234 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

However, I've only got as far as producing the following:

| Week_commencing | Colour | Quantity |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | Blue | 78 |  |  |
| 2021-01-11 | Green | 74 |  |  |
| 2021-02-08 | Blue | 187 |  |  |
| 2021-02-08 | Red | 69 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

This is from the following code:

```
read_csv("C:/temp/testfolder/datestimescolorsnumbers2.csv")

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Week_commencing'] = df['Date'] - df['Date'].dt.weekday * np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

df1 = df.groupby(['Week_commencing', 'Colour']).sum()

print(df1)

df1.to_csv("C:/temp/testfolder/outputGroupByWeek2.csv", encoding="utf-8", index="False")
```

Can I please have pointers on how to turn the rows for Color into columns showing totals for that week? I'm assuming it involves pandas.pivot but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something, can you let me know if this is what you're looking for? :)
It first sets the date column as index, then pivots on the "color" table, and then resamples the `df` with a period of a week.

```py
import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[
            [dt.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 9, 30), "Blue", 13],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 9, 40), "Blue", 78],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 2, 9, 45), "Red", 69],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 9, 9, 55), "Red", 90],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 14, 10, 30), "Red", 24],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 16, 10, 40), "Red", 20],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 22, 10, 45), "Green", 61],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 23, 11, 5), "Blue", 62],
            [dt.datetime(2021, 11, 26, 12), "Blue", 80],
        ],
        columns=["datetime", "colour", "quantity"],
    )

    df = df.set_index("datetime")
    df = df.pivot(columns="colour").resample("W-Mon").sum()
    print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`df` before:

```
                    colour  quantity
datetime                            
2021-10-31 09:30:00   Blue        13
2021-11-01 09:40:00   Blue        78
2021-11-02 09:45:00    Red        69
2021-11-09 09:55:00    Red        90
2021-11-14 10:30:00    Red        24
2021-11-16 10:40:00    Red        20
2021-11-22 10:45:00  Green        61
2021-11-23 11:05:00   Blue        62
2021-11-26 12:00:00   Blue        80
```

`df` after:

```
           quantity             
colour         Blue Green    Red
datetime                        
2021-11-01     91.0   0.0    0.0
2021-11-08      0.0   0.0   69.0
2021-11-15      0.0   0.0  114.0
2021-11-22      0.0  61.0   20.0
2021-11-29    142.0   0.0    0.0
```